# javscript onclick() replace images

Tags: javascript

I try to create a reward card, basically I have a div with 10 images with same id and what I want to achieve is that every time user click a button, images in the div will replace by a new images.

so far with the code below, I only achieve first image replaced than it stops and nothing else happen

```
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Reward Program</h1>
    <div class="section" id="card">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3" id="tut">
         <img src="images/mail.png" id="stamp" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" id="stamp" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" id="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" id="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" id="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" id="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" id="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" id="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" id="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" id="stamp">
         </div>
      </div>

      </div>
  </div>

  <button value="show Check" onclick="showCheck()" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Buy now</button>

var counter = 0,
checked = ["images/check.png", "images/check1.png", "images/check2.png", "images/check3.png", "images/check4.png", "images/check5.png", "images/check6.png", "images/check7.png", "images/check8.png", "images/check9.png"];


showCheck = function  () {


  document.getElementById("stamp").src = checked[counter];
  counter++;

  if (counter >= checked.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }


};
```

Comment: That's because you are running the function only once and there is no loop in it. In order to have looping behavior try using a loop in your function so that way on click you can replace all images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one element ID on a website (each ID has to be unique, otherwise you will get an error), so it's best to change those IDs to classes.

You don't need a loop after all, as you're not changing all the images with a single click of the button, but rather, *one at a time*, so just keep clicking the button.

You can remove the `alt` tag on the images and the `imges[counter].alt = checked[counter]` in the code. I just put it there so you can see what's happening. Run the code snippet to see it working:

```js
var counter = 0;
var checked = ["images/check.png", "images/check1.png", "images/check2.png", "images/check3.png", "images/check4.png", "images/check5.png", "images/check6.png", "images/check7.png", "images/check8.png", "images/check9.png"];

function showCheck() {
  var imges = document.querySelectorAll(".stamp")
  imges[counter].src = checked[counter]
  imges[counter].alt = checked[counter]
  counter++
  if (counter >= checked.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3" id="tut">
      <img src="images/mail.png" alt="mail" class="stamp" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
      <img src="images/mail.png" alt="mail" class="stamp" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
      <img src="images/mail.png" alt="mail" class="stamp">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
      <img src="images/mail.png" alt="mail" class="stamp">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
      <img src="images/mail.png" alt="mail" class="stamp">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
      <img src="images/mail.png" alt="mail" class="stamp">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
      <img src="images/mail.png" alt="mail" class="stamp">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
      <img src="images/mail.png" alt="mail" class="stamp">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
      <img src="images/mail.png" alt="mail" class="stamp">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
      <img src="images/mail.png" alt="mail" class="stamp">
   </div>
</div>

<button value="show Check" onclick="showCheck()" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Buy now</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input mate,  this works but what I want to achieve is the image to be replaced separately every time user click on the button. Imagine a loyality card on coffee shop and you get a stamp every coffee bought. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey @FabioTorti , oh cooool! That sounds awesome! Okay I'll update the answer to work for something like that =)

Comment: Alright @FabioTorti , It's now working for what you want—just keep clicking the button. I've updated the code and will update the description of what's happening now too =)

Comment: No problemo @FabioTorti ! Glad you got it sorted man! Alsooooo, please remember to mark this Q as answered if it solves your issue 

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("tut").src = checked[counter];
```

First of all it looks like you are setting **src** attribute of the `<div>`.
If you want to replace the image you are supposed the set the **src** attribute of the `<img>` inside the `<div>`.
Also the **id** attribute in supposed to be unique for each html element.
If you want several elements to be referred to by a single attribute value use **class** attribute instead.

I have slightly tweaked your code. This should solve your problem.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Reward Program</h1>
    <div class="section" id="card">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" class="stamp" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" class="stamp" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" class="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" class="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" class="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" class="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" class="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" class="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" class="stamp">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
         <img src="images/mail.png" class="stamp">
         </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
<button value="show Check" onclick="showCheck()" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Buy now</button>

var counter = 0,
var checked = ["images/check.png", "images/check1.png", "images/check2.png", "images/check3.png", "images/check4.png", "images/check5.png", "images/check6.png", "images/check7.png", "images/check8.png", "images/check9.png"];
function showCheck() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("stamp").forEach(img=>{
      img.src=checked[counter++];
  });
  if (counter >= checked.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is you are replacing src of only one element. You need to use a loop to replace src of all the elements.

Below is the working snippet of the function:

```
showCheck = function  () {
    $("img[id*='stamp']").each(function(){
       this.src=checked[counter];
    }); 
   counter++;
   if(counter >= checked.length) {
     counter = 0;
    }
  };
```

Comment: thanks Fabio, If the code works, close this discussion.